# Install a Ruby gem to an arbitrary prefix

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'd like to install a Ruby gem to an arbitrary prefix.  For the sake of exposition, I'm trying to install `github-markup`; though, I suspect I'm encountering a general issue rather than anything particular to this package.

In the package's source distribution directory, I've done this:

```
$ gem install --install-dir $HOME/github-markup/lib/ruby/gems --bindir $HOME/github-markup/bin github-markup
```

And, of course, I've added `$HOME/github-markup/bin` to the `PATH`; and I've added `$HOME/github-markup/lib/ruby/gems` to `RUBYLIB`.

But, when I try to run the executable, this happens:

```
$ github-markup my.md
-bash: /usr/local/bin/github-markup: No such file or directory
```

Clearly I'm missing a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: rather than adding that to PATH why not just symlink it into `/usr/local/bin` eg `ln -s ~/github-markup/bin/github-markup /usr/local/bin/github-markup`

Comment: The broader context for this involves installation of various things (but not Ruby itself) beneath a single root. Requiring symlinks outside of that root does not solve the problem.